# Long Minecraft Delays (1.12.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have looked around the internet for methods of having big redstone delays (Up to 5 or 7 minutes), and multiple of these delays in a row, each delay sending a redstone signal to a command block then activating another long redstone delay (Not a loop).

The problem is that I don't want to use a whole lot of repeaters connected between different command blocks, as this would take too long and take up a lot of space. The amount of time also does not need to be too accurate.

What I have found is that many of the solutions I have tried to find are loops (Like Etho's Hopper Timer), and instead of a constant loop I want a redstone delay, like a bunch of repeaters, but more compact.

Anything easy to set up via redstone is preferred but I'm open to using scoreboards.

Edit: I slightly edited Yeet's suggestion so that the command kills the minecart, sand, and also gives an output.

Comment: I seem to recall there being a way to set up a hopper clock as a 1 time pulse with a delay, but I'd have to mess with it to figure out exactly what that would look like

Comment: There may be another better command-centric solution anyway that cuts out redstone altogether. I'll do some research into this.

Comment: ↑ That question is really weird, but the answer is what you want. (And that also means that this is one of the most valuable duplicates I've ever seen, because previously no sane combination of search terms actually lead to a command delay. Now it does. This is the first time I vote to close and also upvote a question, I think.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a possible solution. You could summon a command block minecart riding a falling sand without gravity. After the time nbt tag on the falling sand reaches 600 it will despawn and the minecart will run its command. I made a quick command that replicates my setup. Just put this in a command block and run it:

`summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {Block:stone,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:falling_block,Block:activator_rail,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"gamerule commandBlockOutput false"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"setblock ~ ~3 ~ command_block 0 0 {Command:\"summon falling_block ~2 ~1.5 ~ {Time:-1200, NoGravity:1, Passengers:[{id:commandblock_minecart, Command:\\\"say 60 seconds\\\"}]}\"}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"setblock ~2 ~3 ~ redstone_block"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"setblock ~2 ~4 ~ activator_rail"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"setblock ~ ~ ~1 command_block 0 0 {Command:\"fill ~ ~-3 ~-1 ~ ~ ~ air\"}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"setblock ~ ~-1 ~1 redstone_block"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"kill @e[type=commandblock_minecart,r=1]"}]}]}]}`

Answer (score -1):

The Ethonian hopper clock or something similar would be a good idea.

If you don't want a loop, you could have a hopper that is filled with items, locked by a repeater with a chest underneath. When you want to start the timer, unlock the hopper and have a comparator with a NOT gate directly afterwards, this will cause a redstone signal once all the items have left the hopper.

A command to refill the hopper and empty the chest below can be used.

If you give me a few minutes I can provide screenshots and commands to help